# Guid with extra characters issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, guid, uniqueidentifier

I have a table named `Student`, contain a column `StudentId` as `GUID`, so I used the `Uniqueidentifier` datatype for that.

If I want to get particular record, I get the result by the below query:

```
SELECT * FROM Student WHERE StudentId = '919C3BF9-B081-458C-897D-C0B3FF56AF73'
```

It returns the expected result. But in case if I mistakenly add any extra characters in the end also, it returns the same result. Like the below query:

```
SELECT * FROM Student WHERE StudentId = '919C3BF9-B081-458C-897D-C0B3FF56AF73xyz'
```

If I pass the extra characters in the end of `GUID`, why it is not consider as invalid `GUID`? and return the same result?

Comment: rather user string compare in sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GUID` is 16 bytes, so from the given `919C3BF9-B081-458C-897D-C0B3FF56AF73`

`91` is 1st byte
`9C` is 2nd byte
`3B` is 3rd byte
`F9` is 4th byte
..
..
..
..
`56` is 14th byte
`AF` is 15th byte
`73` is 16th byte

Parsing of `919C3BF9-B081-458C-897D-C0B3FF56AF73xyz` completes before the `xyz`.

So the characters are entered after the 16th byte, won't be consider.

But if you add any extra characters in the front, it won't consider as valid `GUID`.

Moreover, when you query with `GUID`, use the code in between the `{}`.

```
SELECT * FROM Student 
WHERE StudentId = '{919C3BF9-B081-458C-897D-C0B3FF56AF73}'
```

Comment: To add on to this answer, a `uniqueidentifier` data type has a higher data type precedence than varchar so the varchar literal is implicitly converted to uniqueidentifier.  The parsing is apparently more lax without the curly brace enclosure, truncating the extraneous characters in the literal.

Comment: Extra characters within the curly braces result in an error, however extra chars outside `{}` are ignored and truncated.  `SELECT CONVERT(uniqueidentifier ,'{919C3BF9-B081-458C-897D-C0B3FF56AF73}EXTRA')
SELECT CONVERT(uniqueidentifier ,'{919C3BF9-B081-458C-897D-C0B3FF56AF73EXTRA}')`

Comment: Thanks for introducing the `{}` when using with `guid`!

Answer (score 3):

As stated from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx):

> The following example demonstrates the truncation of data when the value is too long for the data type being converted to. Because the uniqueidentifier type is limited to 36 characters, the characters that exceed that length are truncated.

```
DECLARE @ID nvarchar(max) = N'0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0wrong';
SELECT @ID, CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, @ID) AS TruncatedValue;
```

> Here is the result set.

```
String                                       TruncatedValue
-------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------
0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0wrong    0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: msdn even has a similar example detailing the same

Comment: perhaps add this example to demonstrate: `SELECT CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, '919C3BF9-B081-458C-897D-C0B3FF56AF73-This-is-extra')` - produces: `919C3BF9-B081-458C-897D-C0B3FF56AF73`